# Regex to validate a date

Tags: html, regex

so basically, I am creating a booking form for a practice website. I want to validate the date so that the user can only enter a date in 2017, and cannot proceed without entering a date in 2017. They also cannot proceed without entering a valid name and email. An alert message appears if one of these is not satisfied, and the related text boxes are highlighted.

Here is what I have so far in terms of code:

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Booking </title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script>
        function validate{} {
        result = true;
        contentUsername=booking.username.value;
        if (contentUsername=="")
        result=false;
        }

    </script>

    <script>
    function validate() {
        result = true;
        contentUsername=booking.username.value;
        contentEmail=booking.email.value;
        contentDate=booking.date.value;

        var email = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/;
        var username = /^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s\.'-]+[A-Za-z]$/;
        var date = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d).\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d).(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d).\d{2})$/;

        var alertMessage="";


        if (contentUsername==""){
            result=false;
            document.getElementById('username').style.background="lightyellow";
            document.getElementById('username').style.border="solid firebrick 1px";
        }

        if (contentEmail=="") {
            result=false;
            document.getElementById('email').style.background="lightyellow";
            document.getElementById('email').style.border="solid firebrick 1px";
        }

        if (contentDate=="") {
            result=false;
            document.getElementById('date').style.background"lightyellow";
            document.getElementById('date').style.border="solid firebrick 1px";
        }

        if (!(email.test(contact.email.value)) && contact.email.value != "") {
            alertMessage += contact.email.value + ' is not a valid email address.\r\n';
            result=false;
        }

        if (!(username.test(contact.username.value)) && contact.username.value != "") {
            alertMessage += contact.username.value + ' is not a valid name.\r\n';
            result=false;
        }

        if (!(date.test(contact.date.value)) && contact.date.value != "") {
            alertMessage += contact.date.value + ' is not a valid date. Please select a date in 2017.\r\n';
            result=false;
        }

        if (!result) {
            alertMessage += "Please fill out the highlighted fields";
            alert(alertMessage);
        }

        return result;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="branding">
        <img src="Images/logo.png">
    </div><!-- end of "logo" -->
    <div id="tagline">
    <p> Welcome to yourday.com - We hope you enjoy your visit! 
    <br> This is where you can book an appointment with one of our agents!
    <br> Please note: Dates for 2016 are fully booked. Next available appointments are in 2017. We apologies for any inconvenience caused.</p>

    </div><!-- end of "tagline" -->
</div><!-- end of "header" -->

<div id="bodycontent4">
    <form action="http://www.rebol.com/cgi-bin/test-cgi.cgi" method="post" class="booking" id="booking" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Booking</legend>
            <label for="username">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></br>
            <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></br>
            <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date"></br>
            <label for="location">Location:</label>
            <select>
                <option value="manor">Uppercourt Manor</option>
                <option value="killruddery">Killrudderry</option>
                <option value="carriage">The Carriage Rooms</option>
                <option value="coolclogher">Coolclogher House</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div><!--end of "bodycontent" -->



<div id="navigation">
<ul class="topnav" id="TopNav">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

    </li>
</ul>
</div> <!--end of "navigation" -->

<div id="footer" style = "position: absolute; top: 550px;">
  <p>Created by: Calvin Leong</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:calvin.leong@CLDesign.com">calvin.leong@CLDesign.com</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Booking Form */
form.booking label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    color: black;
    line-height: 150%
}

form.booking fieldset {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

form.booking legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}

#bodycontent4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    width: 25%;
    left: 500px;

}

#div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the many cases where using a regex is not appropriate at all. You should instead manipulate a `Date` object and simply check that its year field is 2017. By the way, have you considered how your code should behave in 2017, or even 2018? Maybe checking that the date is in the next year would be more appropriate (and once again regex wouldn't be appropriate for this)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
var date = new Date("01/01/2017");
var year = date.getFullYear();
if(year == 2017){
    alert(year);
}else{
    alert("crap");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regex for date:

```
var date = /^2017-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
```

And, here is the working link: http://jsbin.com/getunisagi

Comment: Thanks for this. I've put it into my code, but it is only validating the year, not the date format i.e. 12/11/2017